# remove a group of inputs in a column based on a single input in a separate column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is a data frame:

```
 df <- data.frame(letter = rep(c("a","b","c","d"), each = 4), number = c(2,1,5,3,9,4,2,4,3,11,1,2,1,1,5,6))
```

I know how to remove a rows based on an observation:

```
rmv <- with(df, number > 8) # finds observations greater than 8
new.df<- df[!rmv, ] # removes observations
```

However, I want to remove all inputs for each letter group (i.e., all the 'b' and 'c' inputs) if there are any observations greater than 8.  Ideal output would be:

```
      letter number
 1       a      2
 2       a      1
 3       a      5
 4       a      3
 13      d      1
 14      d      1
 15      d      5
 16      d      6
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `any`, negate (`!`) after doing a group by 'letter'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(letter) %>% 
   filter(!any(number > 8))
```

---

Or do the reverse with `all`

```
df %>%
   group_by(letter) %>%
   filter(all(number <= 8))
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `ave`

```
df[with(df, ave(number <= 8, letter, FUN = all)),]
```

Comment: `filter(max(number) <= 8)`